# How to check for the 1st day of an year in php

Tags: php, date

How to check weather today is the 1st day of the year or not in php.

edit:
echo date('Y-m-d', strToTime('1/1 this year'));

this code gave me the result. Is this valid or is there better way than this.

Comment: The first day WILL always be 01/01 so why not check for the first day of the first month? (Unless we get conquered by aliens or somehting then they might make the first say 02/04 or something)

Comment: I think he wants to know what is the name of the week day each 1rst january.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the day of the year by passing the format string 'z' do the built-in [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. This will return '0' for the first day, '1' for the second, ... up to '365' for the last day of a (leap) year.

```
if ( date('z') === '0' ) {
    //Today is the first day of the year.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Janis, That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (date('z') === 0) {
echo 'we have 1.1.'
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

[This should solve your problem and more!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

```
<?php
$theDate = date("md"); 
if ($theDate=="0101") echo "It's A New Year!";
?>
```

Date() function formatting characters:

- d - A numeric representation of the day of the month (0 - 31)
- m - A numeric representation of the month of the year (1 - 12)
- y - A numeric representation (two digit) of a year (99, 00, 01, 02)
- H - 24 hour format current hour (00 - 23)
- i - Minutes (00 - 59)
- s - Seconds (00 - 59)

Comment: @Sammaye: If you scroll down, there are scripts to find date and day!

Comment: From a strtotime function, I still don't see how it answers the question

Comment: Thanks guys for your early replies. Actually I want to run a php script in every 1st day of the year (January 01). Therefore I want to validate weather today is the 01st day of the year. Thanks for your ideas and link. I'll check on that.

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka You should look into cronjob scheduling, this cna be done without PHP

Comment: Thanks Sammaye, I am working in windows environment. And I know nothing about cron. Will schedule task do the same? or is it good to do manually allowing the user to click on a link? if the script or something fails then how to automatically redo the job again?

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka Yes schedule task is basically the same. As to the click thing. It depends upon how you want to start the job. This sounds like you only want it to run once a year so I thought cron, as for fail over, you would have to restart it yourself. It is best to use a log with these kinds of scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
if(date('j') == '1' && date('n') == 1){
    // if first day of year
}
```

That will do it easily without any complicated date stuff that you would normally have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

For further informations see http://php.net/date

```
<?php
 if(date('dm',mktime())=="0101")
    echo "fist day of year";
 else
    echo "not the first day";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first day of the year is never different from 1/1/yyyy
You can use strcmp or

```
$now=new DateTime();
```

then use getDay GetMonth from $now to evaluate

Answer (score 0):

If you were interested in the name of the first day of the year

```
echo date('l', strtotime('2012-01-01'));
```

OR

```
echo date('l', strtotime("first day of January 2012"));

Output:// Sunday

OR

just use -

echo (date('z') === 0) ? 'First day' : 'Not first day';

//z     The day of the year (starting from 0)   0 through 365
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do following :

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of january " . date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function has a `z` format character, which can be used for this:

```
$day_of_year = date('z');
// $day_of_year is 259 for the day I write this
```